# Ловим спамеров с помощью RegExp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В общем одолели спамеры которые хотят что-то продать, поэтому решил менять все, что содержит корень "прода" на звездочки. Написал такое регулярное выражение:

`(?:п|p)(?:.+|)(?:р|r)(?:.+|)(?:о|o|0)(?:.+|)(?:д|d)(?:.+|)(?:а|a)`

которое успешно ловит такие варианты:

> `продаю pродаю пrodaю prodaю п р о д  а ю пр0дам п-р-о-даю п..r__0*дaм`

Но что-то как-то громоздко получилось, возможно есть варианты как это дело упростить?

Comment: сам не распознаешь.  изобретательные продаваны напишут свой текст из слепо-символов брайля, чтобы получились русские буквы )))  покажи чатгпт картинку твоего текста и спроси "что тут продают".  если он не знает - то значит спама нет )))

Comment: правда, после этого продаваны напишут "я не продам вам слона", и чатгпт скажет что ничего не продают, но покупатели всё равно поймут ))))

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Квадратные скобки используй для групп символов.
И звёздочку для 0 и более сиволов.

```
[пp].*[рr].*[оo0].*[дd].*[аa]
```

А вообще, всё это бесполезно, похожих букв гораздо больше:

> ΠᑭꄲᎷ слона.

А ещё будет огромное количество false positive:

> в ПеРвый день на ОгороДе посеяли семенА Мальвы.